# Rails 4: undefined method `permit' for "xxxx xxxx":String

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I have a search model that I hope to use in conjunction with sunspot to handle all searches across different models. I'm stuck before I even have gotten started.

Here is the form that appears in the header of all the web pages on my site.

```
      <%= simple_form_for @search, :url => searches_path, :method => :post do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
```

In my searches_controller

```
 def search_params
     params.require(:search).permit(:search)
 end
```

In my Search.rb

```
    attr_accessor :search
```

When I plug in my name into it I get this error

```
   undefined method `permit' for "simon walsh":String
```

Parameters:

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"1Tez0pnMILEciLR6j+li+qSeO4NYBj3XsB6dYG07RymsiNUNSAGI5ztpMiD4JNAtTnqwJYdHTpPBRqGduWHjBw==",
  "search"=>"simon walsh",
   "commit"=>"Search"}
```

I am confused. This is clearly a simple error with the way I am posting the params. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
def search_params
    params.require(:search).permit!
end
```

Instead of this:

```
def search_params
    params.require(:search).permit(:search)
end
```

This issue may occur because of string parameter in `params["search"]`, while in controller you are using `.permit(:search)`, or maybe you have an attribute and model name that are the same.